disable change .ts to .js on autocomplete
[webstorm] How to disable the behavior of changing .ts to .js on autocomplete ?
Pure TS project (without generating any .js files, which already transform by esm loader)

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports | Use file extension: Never

How to disable the behavior of changing .ts to .js on autocomplete in WebStorm:

Go to settings

macOS: WebStorm > Preferences (Cmd + ,)
Windows/Linux: File > Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)


Adjust TypeScript Autocomplete

Navigate to Editor > General > Auto Import and modify settings to prevent unwanted changes from .ts to .js.


Check File Associations

Go to Editor > File Types and ensure .ts is correctly associated under TypeScript and not JavaScript.


Manage File Watchers

Disable any TypeScript to JavaScript conversion in Tools > File Watchers if necessary.


Confirm Changes and Restart

Click Apply or OK, then restart WebStorm to ensure settings take effect.



